# Oracle SQL select within select

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So I have `reason` identified as some kind of ID in table1. I need to write query which writes out the belonging meaning of a reason from table 2. I hope my bad english was enough to explain my problem.

table1

```
    id  reason
  --------------
    1     1
    2     2
    3     1
```

table2

```
domain         value  meaning
------------------------------
table1.reason    1    example1
table1.reason    2    example2
```

I tried this select but i got error "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row" but if I add `max()` on `t2.meaning` it only returns me meaning example2 because max value = 2

```
select 
    t1.id
    (select t2.meaning
    from table2 t2, table1 t1
    where t2.value = t1.reason
    and t2.domain = 'table1.reason') as reason
from table1;
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  The error seems quite clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you just want a correlated subquery, not a `join`:

```
select t1.id
       (select t2.meaning
        from table2 t2
        where t2.value = t1.reason and
              t2.domain = 'table1.reason'
       ) as reason
from table1;
```